# Chapter 9 (new) Rails Tutorial console exercise: undefined method `remember_token' for #<Class:0x00000004ab1dd8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I searched all of stackoverflow for an answer, but still don't know what to do.
The exercise ask me to:

> Assign user to the first user in the database, and verify by calling it directly that the remember method works.

So should I call:

```
user.remember
```

This gives me error

```
undefined method `remember_token' for #<Class:0x00000004ab1dd8>
```

I did:

```
rails generate migration add_remember_digest_to_users remember_digest:string 
rails db:migrate
```

The user.rb:`enter code here`

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_save { email.downcase! }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine::cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.   Listing 9.2: Adding a method for generating     tokens.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember      # Listing 9.3: Adding a remember method to the User     model. green
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end
end
```

I ran 'rails test' with 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips!

Comment: should be rake db:migrate, not rails db:migrate

Comment: @JorgedelosSantos in RoR5 it works - _"One Rails Command instead of the split-brain setup between rake and rails, so now it’s `bin/rails db:migrate` instead of `bin/rake db:migrate`"_

Comment: Can you also post code for your `remember` method? From your error, it seems that the `remember` method requires `remember_token` attribute, not `remember_digest`.

Comment: @Vucko: the text says:
"Note the form of the assignment in the first line of the remember method. Because of the way Ruby handles assignments inside objects, without self the assignment would create a local variable called remember_token, which isn’t what we want. Using self ensures that assignment sets the user’s remember_token attribute."

I have read and re-read the paragraph, and followed the instructions to the letter, afaik.

Comment: OK; I have to say I'm sorry. I overlooked the line 2 to be added to user.rb:

        attr_accessor :remember_token

  No error now, any more

Answer (score 0):

You have to first assign the first user to user and then call the remember method

the way you do it is

> > user = User.first
> >     user.remember